# odbc execution time issues with sql server and SAS

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc

i've written an sql query that has a run time of about 14 seconds when i run it on ms management studio, but as soon as i try to run the query via explicit sql pass-through in SAS EG or DI using ODBC the run time exceeds 20 (!!!) hours.

I've boiled down the issue to the buffer size option in the connection string, when the buffer size is set to zero, the execution time is about 14 to 17 seconds. on examination of the sas trace log i've noticed that when the buffer size is set to any number other then 0 the fetch phase of the odbc engine consumes about 99% of the long process time.

I'm inclined to leave the buffer at zero but i have a feeling the my SQL server DBA will be more then upset with that, as the sql server is writing one row at a time to SAS. unfortunetly OLE DB is not an option so i cant compare methods. any one has any idea about whats going on?

Comment: This sounds like an issue for SAS technical support. I suggest you try contacting them directly. Otherwise, code / log excerpts would be helpful here.

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using? What is your connection config (whether DSN or connect string)? What SAS settings are you using (`READBUFF`, `INSERTBUFF`, others)? There are too many missing details to provide cogent advice.

Comment: Try these options instead: bulkload=yes dbcommit=100000

Comment: i'm using a connection string:  DEFER=YES READBUFF=1000 INSERT_SQL=YES INSERTBUFF=32000 UPDATE_MULT_ROWS=YES AUTOCOMMIT=YES DATASRC=AML AUTHDOMAIN="*******"; and the ODBC driver is SQL server native client 11